# Fragment removal code is not working after screen orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

iam beginner in Android programming...
iam adding Fragments into a Layout using the following codes

```
                Fragment f=new Jobcat();
    FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft =fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.jobcategoryfragment, f,"A");
    ft.commit();
                ft.add(R.id.jobcategoryfragment, f,"C");
    ft.commit();
    ft.add(R.id.jobcategoryfragment, f,"B");
    ft.commit();
```

and iam removing the Fragment using the following code..

```
Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B");
   FragmentTransaction ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.remove(f);
   ft.commit();
```

It's working well if the screen orientation is not changed...if i changed the screen orientation or even if i got back orientation to orginal state after that iam getting runtime error

> 04-02 17:02:23.051: W/dalvikvm(8937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41082930)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:651)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   04-02 17:02:23.051: E/AndroidRuntime(8937):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

can anyone help me for finding a solution for this problem...

Thank you

Comment: please paste error log as well

Comment: please post the entire logcat

Comment: try  android:configChanges="" in your activity ,in which you are adding the fragment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

in the androidmanifest.xml where the current activity is described...

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException occurs because the fragment may no longer be added to your activity after the configuration change. This happens if the Fragment is not retained during configuration changes.

You have two options:

1. In your Jobcat-Fragment add setRetained(true); to your onCreate() method. With this your fragment will survive the Orientation Change and be readded to your activity with the same TAG as before. This is not recommended to do with fragments having a GUI to avoid leakages, but sometimes I found there was no other convenient way to achieve this.
2. Check if

   Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B") -> null

If so there is no need to remove the fragment from your activity because it isn't there anymore anyway.